# OpenCV build in debug mode with optimizations?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, intel-vtune, intel-parallel-studio

I'm trying to profile OpenCV using [Intel VTune Amplifier](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe). In [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/605665) page, there is a list of compiler options suggested to obtain the best analysis.

As you can see, it's a mix of debug flags (e.g. `-g`) and optimization flags (e.g. `-O2` or higher), so we can say it suggest "a release mode with debugging information".

In order to profile OpenCV with VTune, I think I have to build it with these options too. However, OpenCV is built with CMAKE, and using `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` will produce optimization flags (though I don't know which ones, I suppose `-O3` or similars) without debugging options and viceversa using `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`.

In conclusion, it seems that I can't build OpenCV with both `-g` and `-O2` flags, which are both highly recommended for profiling application using VTune. Am I right?

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html

Use `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo` to get both optimization flags and debug info.

Comment: Sir, you saved my day, thank you. Does this include `-O0` option? Because citing [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/605665): "do not use Debug Build or `-O0`"

Comment: `make VERBOSE=1` will show you the commands it runs so you can see exactly what flags are used.   -O0 is no optimization, so it doesn't seem like a release build would have that, but just check to see for yourself to make sure.